# I am attempting to create/activate a virtual environment in VSC python

Tags: python

I created a virtual environment in my command prompt and python works in command prompt but when I try do it from VSC I get the following message after entering `-m venv .venv`

```
PS C:\Users\jefim> -m venv .venv
-m : The term '-m' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ -m venv .venv
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-m:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: It should be `python -m venv .venv`

Comment: you're missing the `python` part of that command `python -m venv .venv`

Comment: ah how foolish of me thank you very very much xD